# How can someone see suggested edits in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I'm studying different kinds of answers in developers' discussion forums. As I know, Stack Overflow provides a mechanism called **Suggest Edits** by which people can edit answers given by other users, though the proposed edit needs to be approved by other users who have required privilege.

Can anybody help me to see some of these edit suggests?

Comment: You can only review edits that were done by another user on one of *your* posts. IIRC, you need 3K reputation to review all suggested edits

Comment: Yes I know I have not the privilege and I won't have a direct access. I'm wondering if someone can send me some of them. For example, it would be great if I can see some of the answers which have bug and other have suggested bug-fixes.

Comment: No. Gain reputation. Get the privilege. Review suggested edits. That is the only way

Comment: How does accessing suggested edits give you access to incomplete answers?  What are you expecting to see in these suggested edits?

Comment: by an incomplete answer I meant an answer which may have not a successful execution in a programming environment due to a bug in the given code snippet, or may lack some statements which reduces the expressiveness of the given answer.

Comment: Once the suggested edits are approved, you will get to see them. Be patient, as it only takes a few minutes for edits to be approved and visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to view suggested edits before they're approved, you must have access to the "Suggested Edits" review queue, which requires 2,000 reputation and is part of the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) moderation privilege.

However, anyone can view edits after approval, by clicking the "edited" link under a post. And anyone can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to find such posts.

The following query generates a list of links to threads in which an answer has been edited. Modify it as desired and then enter it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to run it.

```
SELECT TOP 50 CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/', Id) FROM Posts
WHERE LastEditDate IS NOT NULL
  AND PostTypeId = 2  -- answers only
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can I see the changes? Is there any way to compare what has been posted originally with the improved (edited) post?

Comment: Sure. Consider your own question, which you've edited. Click the "edited x hours ago" link underneath it, and then either select "inline" or "side-by-side" to view the changes between one edit and another.